# Find amount sold to "reactivated" customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the following:
A list of customers and the amount ($) sold to them between initial and final dates (call them D1 and D2) **IF** the following is met: the time between the previous sale to the first sale between D1 and D2 is greater than some amount X.

---

*Example:*

D1 = Jan 1 2020, D2 = Dec 31 2020, X = 1 year.

Customer John's first purchase of 2020 was on Jan 15 2020, and his previous purchase was on May 15 2019. Therefore, John shouldn't appear on the list (since less than a year elapsed between these two dates).

Customer Bob's first purchase of 2020 was on Feb 15 2020, and his previous purchase was on Jan 10 2019. Bob *should* appear on the list together with the total amount sold to him between D1 and D2.

---

I've tried to use `max()` to find the last date where a purchase was done subject to the condition that it be before D1. Something like:

```
select max(date)
from Sales
where date<:D1
```

Obviously I can do a similar thing (via `min()`) to find the first date of purchase after D1. But how do I do these 2 things simultaneously?

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic with window functions.  The following is pseudo-code because your question doesn't even properly name the columns in the data.  However, it should be easy to follow:

```
select customer, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when date < @d1 then date end) over (partition by customer) as pre_date,
             min(case when date >= @d1 then date end) over (partition by customer) as post_date
      from t
     ) t
where pre_date < dateadd(year, -1, post_date) and
      date >= @d1 and
      date <= @d2
group by customer;
```

Comment: Wow this did it (with a few tweaks here and there)! You're awesome, man, thank you!